# Bidirectional Encoder Representations from Transformers in R

Tags: nlp, r, text, programming

Can anybody suggest to me, where I can find example code for R language for BERT neural network for text mining tasks. All I can see are python examples, and I need R.

- https://github.com/google-research/bert
- https://github.com/facebookresearch/XNLI
- https://github.com/tensorlayer/seq2seq-chatbot
- https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/named-entity-recognition-with-bert/
- https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT и чат ботов
- https://stanfordnlp.github.io/coqa/
- https://github.com/nyu-dl/bert-gen

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in the open-source R package RBERT:
https://github.com/jonathanbratt/RBERT

It's a work in progress, but the goal is to be able to use BERT directly in R.

Comment: While you'll need python to be installed, you don't need to code in python. RBERT (github.com/jonathanbratt/RBERT) lets you do everything in R.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Python dependency is always there in some fashion. I found [this nice example](https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2020-07-30-state-of-the-art-nlp-models-from-r/) of bridging that gap via reticulate:

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: Only performs text classification (for now)**

*For general purpose tasks, I recommend RBERT*

I've developed a package on CRAN called [*transforEmotion*](https://cran.r-project.org/package=transforEmotion)

There is a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/transforEmotion/vignettes/Python_Setup.pdf) to get set up with Python (includes example of how to use package in R at the end)

After, the rest is taken care of in the `transformer_scores()` function.

The default model on CRAN is [Facebook's BART Large](https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large-mnli)

I've done much more work on [GitHub](https://github.com/AlexChristensen/transforEmotion)

The default model on GitHub is [Cross-Encoder's DistilRoBERTa](https://huggingface.co/cross-encoder/nli-distilroberta-base) (much faster than Facebook's BART Large with minimal trade-off for accuracy)

The `transformer_scores()` function allows you to implement any [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/) text classification pipeline so long as there is a pipeline for it: https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=zero-shot-classification